# selecting a select_list item using ruby and watir and firefox

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is my first time using ruby and watir. I have installed Firefox 45.4.0 and ruby 2.4.1 and ruby gems 2.6.12 and watir 6.2.1 and the geckodriver-0.16.1 on Linux bsg-gnorris2 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

For the most part, things are working well.  I am having trouble selecting items in a select list. Here is the code that creates the select list:

```
<div><div class="form-item form-item-court form-type-select form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="edit-court">Court
<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>>
<select class="form-control form-select required" id="edit-court" name="court">
<option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option>
  <option value="1127">Alabama - Middle</option>
  <option value="1126">Alabama - North</option>
  <option value="1128">Alabama - South</option>
...
...
  <option value="0757">Wisconsin - East</option>
  <option value="0758">Wisconsin - West</option>
  <option value="1089">Wyoming</option>
</select></div>
```

The code navigates fine to a page that has the select list above.
Then, when I try to select a select_list option, nothing happens and no error messages are produced.

Here is what I have tried:

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'edit-court').select_value '1126'
(nothing visible happens - no error messages)

browser.select_list(:id => 'edit-court').select 'Alabama - North'
(nothing visible happens - no error messages)

browser.select_list(:id => 'edit-court').select /Alabama - North/
(nothing visible happens - no error messages)

browser.element(:id => 'edit-court').wait_until_present.click (this shows list options)
browser.element(:id => 'edit-court').option(:value, '1126').wait_until_present.select (this hides list options)

browser.element(:id => 'edit-court').wait_until_present.click (this shows list options)
browser.element(:id => 'edit-court').option(:value, '1126').wait_until_present.click (this hides list options)

browser.element(:id => 'edit-court').wait_until_present.click (this shows list options)
browser.select_list(:id => 'edit-court').options[3].click (hides the list options)
```

I am at a loss for what to do next.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem using the supplied HTML on `watir 6.2.1`, `ruby 2.2.6`, firefox 53.0.3 + `geckodriver 0.16.1` on windows.  Firefox 45.4.0 is pretty stale, and that's right around the time that FF switched to geckodriver.  You might want to try updating FF to latest.

Comment: Thanks.  That's something I have considered.  One thing I was hoping to get from this was confirmation that updating FF may help resolve my issue.  I'll talk to our system administrator about that.

Comment: You have to use different configurations with Watir > 6 and Firefox < 48. At this point, definitely upgrade your Firefox. :)

Comment: @GeorgeNorris Only problem in your case is Geckodriver, nothing else. Your browser version is absolutely fine. I have the same problem for myself. All you need to do is, you need to use legacy firefox driver not geckodriver. If you don't know what to do to use geckodriver, I will update an answer for that. Never go for geckodriver, it still have many problem. And don't upgrade your browser, it's completely unnecessary, If you still want to move further, go for 47.0.2,that's the last version we can use legacy firefox driver.

Comment: One suggestion from is is to add `binding.pry` at the point you see a problem. You will enter into a pry shell where you can call any methods and see the results. `ls object`,  `cd object`, etc. very powerful.